# How to view final product of a string with escape characters using R

Tags: r, firefox, escaping

I have passed a string (literally) `"E:\temp"` to firefox browser (as default preference to saving file) but it got a value of `E<tab>emp` - it didn't work.
While I passed `"E:\\temp"` it got nothing (empty field which didn't work)
While I passed `"E:%5Ctemp"` it got `E:%5Ctemp⁩` - this works but name of storage folder is `%5Ctemp` on disk E

How to escape backslash and \t to get `E:\temp` in that browser settings?

Comment: I've managed to do this (on Windows) by passing just `"E:temp" ` without backslash nor slash.

Comment: Haven't tested but maybe `as.character(noquote("E:\\temp"))`